# How to read and edit excel files with python

Tags: python, excel

I am fairly new to python and am trying to do the following:

I have an excel data sheet with two columns. The first containing the name and the second containing the data. If I had a name to the program it needs to find that name in the spreadsheet move one cell to the right (next column) read the value. After that, I have a small formula that changes the value and then I want to store that data in the same cell it came from.

After that, it starts all over again.

Now I know that I need to use xlsxwriter for this job, but I'm not able the come up with the right code. I found this page:
https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-excel-tutorial#gs.WWHel8Q
but it isn't quite what I'm looking for. I'm not asking you guys to hand me a code, but could you help me out in the right direction? (In fact, I rather write the code myself because it is a great way to learn Python by just doing it).

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('Test.xlsx')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Test.xlsx')
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Name" :['A' ,'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
     "Value" :[1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5 ,6]},
    )
df.to_excel(writer,'Main_sheet')
value = df.loc[lambda df: df.Name == 'D',:]
p = value.Value + 50
print(value)
print(p)
df.set_value(value.index, 'Name', 10)

writer.save()
```

I now got this. But it does not work, the value for D stays 4. why is that?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. I appreciate you noting that you aren't trying to ask for someone to code for you. However, your question still does not meet the community guidelines found in [ask]. Stack Overflow is more for helping with specific coding problems. A more effective and accepted way to ask would be to attempt the problem yourself and then if there is any specific part your don't understand, or errors you can't get through, ask about those. That helps both you learn what you can do yourself, and us by challenging us to come up with more creative answers than "Look here"

Comment: I'm sorry, I was hoping someone could lead me in the right direction. Just like Andrey did with his answer about pandas, which is really helpfull btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try pandas. You'll be able to read the whole table and make operations on it. Learning how to use pandas isn't difficult, but it is very useful.

http://pandas.pydata.org/

You will be able to do something like this:

```
df = pd.read_excel('filename')
df.loc[df.col1 == 'name', col2] = formula
```

At first you read the file. Then you find a value in the first column and modify the value in this row in the second column.

**UPD**:

Here is the solution for your case. As I said, you can directly modify value in the dataframe. The code finds row with 'D' in column "Name" and adds 50 to the value in column 'Value'.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Name" :['A' ,'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
     "Value" :[1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5 ,6]},
    )

df.loc[df.Name == 'D', 'Value'] += 50

df
Name    Value
0   A   1
1   B   2
2   C   3
3   D   54
4   E   5
5   F   6

df.to_excel('Test.xlsx')
```

Comment: hmmm i cant get it to work. I tried your line but i got an error for col1. So i tried something else (see edited post) which still doesn't work haha. It is so frustrating sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

It happens I've wrote one function earlies using **openpyxl**

```
import openpyxl
import os


def load_FromExcel(filepath, total_row = 999999999999):
    """Using module "openpyxl" to load data from excel file(only support '.xlsx' format)

    Make sure you already install "openpyxl".
    :param filepath:
        Source file should be put under the path beneath the file which is calling this method.
        Otherwise you'll have to change some code inside.
    :return:
        list_row is a list consists of list records.
        For example, list_row[0] is a list consists of these cell in 1st row.
        Therefore, use list_row[0][0] represent the value in 1st column in 1st row(A1).
    """
    filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__) + "/../" + filepath)
    # Use "os.path.dirname(__file__)" to get a relevant path
    print(filename)
    # Open a workbook by name= filename in READ-ONLY mode
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename, read_only=True)
    # Select this worksheet
    sheet = wb.get_active_sheet()
    sheet_rows = tuple(sheet.rows)
    # This is the total amount of rows in the excel file opened
    row_count = len(sheet_rows)
    print(row_count)
    row_count = 0
    list_row = []
    for row in sheet.rows:
        row_count += 1
        temp_list = []
        for cell in row:
            # print(cell.value,end=',')
            temp_list.append(cell.value)
        list_row.append(temp_list)
        if row_count > total_row:
            break
    print("Loading Complete")
    return list_row
```

And please do keep yourself clean to what you're coding before using your codes.